# Mapp new table from database

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, intellij-idea

I am trying to map new table from database using JPA and intelij. I already have persistance.xml file which but when i need to chose persistance unit, its not there for me to select and i do not want to create another one for one file.. Here is screenshot.

As you cen see i cannot chose persistance.xml in META-INF folder. How can i deal with it? Thanks for help.

[image]

Comment: Since you say you want to specify a **JPA persistence.xml** file and it is prompting for a "Hibernate configuration file" then you can safely assume that you didn't click on a JPA persistence.xml option. Hibernate config file is not the same thing!!!!!

Comment: i see... where can i chose JPA persistance option?

Comment: Check the corresponding [dialog options](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/generate-persistence-mapping-import-dialogs.html#db_mapping) for the **Add to Persistence Unit / Add to Session Factory** option.